# When SQLite column is true, add class to list element

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite

I have some code here which dynamically generates a list:

```
transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE checkb = "true" ORDER BY date DESC', [],
                      function(transaction, result) {
                      if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
                      for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                      var row = result.rows.item(i);
                      $('#mylist').append('<li data-rowid="' + row['Id'] + '"><a href ="#">'+ 'test: ' + row['test'] +'</a></li>');
                      }
                      }
                      },errorHandler);
               },errorHandler,nullHandler);
```

from the select statement I have a condition to only select if checkb is true.  However, is there a way to add a class to the list element being generated if checkb is true?

Comment: See the select statement? Sorry should have mentioned that the column checkb contains the true/false value of a checkbox

Comment: so you want to only append the li if checkb  is true??

Comment: No that was just an example to show the column.  I want to change the class of the appended list element if checkb is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```js
(row['checkb'] == 'true')? 'class="className"' : ''
```

check `(row['checkb'] == 'true')` if condition is true add class `'class="className"'` if false add nothing `''`

---

```js
$('#mylist')
.append('<li '+((row['checkb'] == 'true')? 'class="className"' : '') + 'data-rowid="' + row['Id'] + '"><a href ="#">'+ 'test: ' + row['test'] +'</a></li>');
```

---

**Update**

```js
var cls = (row['checkb'] == 'true')? 'class="className"' : ''; //assign class to variable
$('#mylist')
    .append('<li '+ cls + 'data-rowid="' + row['Id'] + '"><a href ="#">'+ 'test: ' + row['test'] +'</a></li>');
```

Comment: If it's true, the list element just displays this:  class = "className"  it might be something to do with the quotation marks